# Laravel/PHP - query on large data and problem with error 500

Tags: php, laravel, large-data

I filter job offers on data from a database. As long as the table contained up to 10,000 records, everything worked great.

```
$searchQuery = \App\JobOffers::searchOffer($search_text, $search_location, $job_function, $job_type, $job_experience, $date_filter, $last);
```

Now the table has over 60,000 records with job offers. When I wants to perform filtering, the application returns error 500.

I can't find a solution to this problem.

I thought about using 'chunk'. I don't know if this solution will help.

```
foreach ($all->chunk(100) as $key => $chunk) {
    $chunk = $chunk->all();

    $test = $chunk::searchOffer($search_text, $search_location, $job_function, $job_type, $job_experience, $date_filter, $last);
    $searchQuery->push($test);
}
```

In the above example I get an error: "Class name must be a valid object or a string".

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can't use `::searchOffer` (static methods) in a variable. That's the first problem I see there. It must be a class or namespace. Have you thought about doing a raw SQL query to the database with your custom restraints?

Comment: Of course you can bind a `function()` to a `$variable`.
If your using `Laravel Scout`, you forgotten to `->get()` to the end of `$searchQuery`